# Remove host from host map in Hacknet

Tags: hacknet

I'm pretty far through Hacknet and my hosts window looks like this:

[image]

How do I clean up here (i.e. remove some of the hosts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apparently](https://steamcommunity.com/app/365450/discussions/0/530649887212917279/) they are placed randomly and can't be moved or removed, unless you edit your save manually. (It will get much worse as you progress, I'm afraid.)